# How can I convert a String to a Symbol in Runtime in Scala?

Tags: string, scala, symbols

I have a case class that looks like this:

```
case class Outcome(text: Symbol)
```

Now I need to change the value of text at runtime. I try to do something like this:

```
val o2 = o1.copy(text.name = "foo" ++ text.name)
```

This obviously gives me a compilation error:

```
type mismatch; found : String required: Symbol
```

How can I convert a symbol to string, append/prepend something and again change it to a symbol? Or to be more simple, how can I change the name of a symbol?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use `Symbol.apply` method:

```
Symbol("a" + "b")
// Symbol = 'ab

val o2 = o1.copy(text = Symbol("foo" + o1.text.name))
```

There is a useful tool to work with nested structures in [`scalaz`](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz) - [`Lens`](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Lens.html)

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

case class Outcome(symbol: Symbol)
val symbolName = Lens.lensu[Symbol, String]( (_, str) => Symbol(str), _.name)
val outcomeSymbol =
  Lens.lensu[Outcome, Symbol]( (o, s) => o.copy(symbol = s), _.symbol)
val outcomeSymbolName = outcomeSymbol >=> symbolName

val o = Outcome('Bar)

val o2 = outcomeSymbolName.mod("foo" + _, o)
// o2: Outcome = Outcome('fooBar)
```